# Redirecting "url a" to "url b" without changing "url a" in the browser

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, nginx

I'm redirecting `vfd.com/blog` to a wordpress site in `fufu.com/vfd`.

What I did was configuring my nginx (vfd.com) like so:

```
location = /blog {
    return 301 http://fufu.com/vfd;
}
```

And then I want to rewrite `fufu.com/vfd` (apache) so that the browser will show `vfd.com/blog` :

```
RewriteEngine On
...

RewriteRule /vfd http://vfd.com/blog
```

When I tested by running `vfd.com/blog` it will still point to `fufu.com/vfd`.

What am I missing here to retain `http://vfd.com/blog`?
Or are there any alternatives

**Update 1**

I tried setting up a proxy like so:

```
location = /blog {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host fufu.com;
    proxy_redirect http://fufu.com/vfd http://vfd.com/blog;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

What I get now is a 404. Checking the logs it says that it cannot find "/blog".
Why would it still require "/blog" if im serving the contents from fufu.com/vfd to vfd.com/blog? What am I still missing here?

Comment: @anubhava This one: http://vfd.com/blog. Updated the question too.

Comment: But isn't `return 301 http://fufu.com/vfd` redirecting to `http://fufu.com/vfd`? I think you may need to use a proxy from `vfd.com` to `fufu.com`

Comment: @anubhava Like so?

  location = /blog {
    proxy_pass http://fufu.com/vfd;
  }

Comment: Yes probably but I don't know much about nginx

Comment: @anubhava Tried proxy and now I'm getting a 404. Seems a bit of a small progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wew. Solved it. The config should be:

```
location /blog {
    proxy_pass http://fufu.com/vfd;
    proxy_set_header Host fufu.com;
    proxy_redirect http://fufu.com/vfd http://vfd.com/blog;
}
```

The apache's `.htaccess` won't matter. The debt now here is that the contents of `vfd.com/blog` still point to sub-directories of `fufu.com/vfd`. Will investigate this further.